# Python distutils, how to get a compiler that is going to be used?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, installation, distutils

For example, I may use `python setup.py build --compiler=msvc` or `python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32` or just `python setup.py build`, in which case the default compiler (say, `bcpp`) will be used. How can I get the compiler name inside my setup.py (e. g. `msvc`, `mingw32` and `bcpp`, respectively)?

UPD.: I don't need the default compiler, I need the one that is **actually** going to be used, which is not necessarily the default one. So far I haven't found a better way than to parse `sys.argv` to see if there's a `--compiler...` string there.

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to include an extra `stdint.h` header for msvc, but not other compilers.

Answer (score 36):

This is an expanded version of Luper Rouch's answer that worked for me to get an openmp extension to compile using both mingw and msvc on windows. After subclassing build_ext you need to pass it to setup.py in the cmdclass arg. By subclassing build_extensions instead of finalize_options you'll have the actual compiler object to look into, so you can then get more detailed version information. You could eventually set compiler flags on a per-compiler, per-extension basis:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext
copt =  {'msvc': ['/openmp', '/Ox', '/fp:fast','/favor:INTEL64','/Og']  ,
     'mingw32' : ['-fopenmp','-O3','-ffast-math','-march=native']       }
lopt =  {'mingw32' : ['-fopenmp'] }

class build_ext_subclass( build_ext ):
    def build_extensions(self):
        c = self.compiler.compiler_type
        if copt.has_key(c):
           for e in self.extensions:
               e.extra_compile_args = copt[ c ]
        if lopt.has_key(c):
            for e in self.extensions:
                e.extra_link_args = lopt[ c ]
        build_ext.build_extensions(self)

mod = Extension('_wripaca',
            sources=['../wripaca_wrap.c', 
                     '../../src/wripaca.c'],
            include_dirs=['../../include']
            )

setup (name = 'wripaca',
   ext_modules = [mod],
   py_modules = ["wripaca"],
   cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext_subclass } )
```

Comment: it should be noted that for gcc/clang under linux/posix the keyname for lopt has to be 'unix'

Comment: Thanks. The information really ought to be more accessible than that. We should report a bug to distutils

Answer (score 9):

You can subclass the `distutils.command.build_ext.build_ext` command.

Once `build_ext.finalize_options()` method has been called, the compiler type is stored in `self.compiler.compiler_type` as a string (the same as the one passed to the `build_ext`'s `--compiler` option, e.g. 'mingw32', 'gcc', etc...).

Comment: The compiler object is `self.compiler`, the type is in `self.compiler.compiler_type`

Comment: The `compiler_type` is set in the `build_ext.run` method from `distutils`. So if you have a `build_ext` subclass and overridden the `run` method, `compiler_type` might never be set.

Answer (score 2):

```py
#This should work pretty good
def compilerName():
  import re
  import distutils.ccompiler
  comp = distutils.ccompiler.get_default_compiler()
  getnext = False

  for a in sys.argv[2:]:
    if getnext:
      comp = a
      getnext = False
      continue
    #separated by space
    if a == '--compiler'  or  re.search('^-[a-z]*c$', a):
      getnext = True
      continue
    #without space
    m = re.search('^--compiler=(.+)', a)
    if m == None:
      m = re.search('^-[a-z]*c(.+)', a)
    if m:
      comp = m.group(1)

  return comp


print "Using compiler " + '"' + compilerName() + '"'
```

Comment: Regular expressions are not needed here and should be compiled when they are used multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.argv.extend(['--compiler', 'msvc'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class BuildWithDLLs(build):

    # On Windows, we install the git2.dll too.
    def _get_dlls(self):
        # return a list of of (FQ-in-name, relative-out-name) tuples.
        ret = []
        bld_ext = self.distribution.get_command_obj('build_ext')
        compiler_type = bld_ext.compiler.compiler_type
```

You can use self.distribution.get_command_obj('build_ext') to get build_ext instance,
and then get the compiler_type

Answer (score -1):

import distutils.ccompiler

compiler_name = distutils.ccompiler.get_default_compiler()

Comment: This is not necessarily the compiler that distutils is going to use!