# Understanding Python path variables, module installation/import and version management

Tags: python, macos, module, path

I am learning Python, I have a very limited understanding of Unix, path management, etc.. 
My goal is to use Python2.5.x with several modules. The native install of Python2.7 can see all of my modules. The native 2.5 cannot. Additionally, I have installed the binary for 2.5.4 from Python.org. I am using the latest release of Xcode (4.6) with command line tools installed, and m OS X (10.8.3)

When I built the Python 2.5 build of [PIL library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/index.htm) (ie. `python setup.py -build_ext -i; python setup.py install`), *initially*, this was no problem, except that it wasn't accessible to the native 2.5 install at all, but rather 2.7! So, after installing 2.5.4, I tried to build PIL again, hoping that it would follow the updated path variables. Alas, 2.5.4 wants to use GCC 4.0.1 and thus can't complete the build.

By symlinking the modules from where they are to the places I need them to be (or in the case of [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/), simply made a copy of the entire directory because, for some reason, symlinking didn't work), I can get my current install to load them. But I know this must be the wrong way to do it, and I just don't understand how, for example, something installed to

`Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/site-packages`

is supposed to be made accessible to other versions.

**TLDR:**

It is this sense of helplessness in terms of getting things to work together that is so frustrating. How is this *supposed*  to work? What is the point of binary installer or even setup scripts if I can't control which versions of Python can access which modules? I would be hugely grateful if anyone can point me to a concise explaination of what is happening when modules install and when python loads them so I can learn to diagnose these problems myself.

---

*Here is all the information I could think up that I thought might be helpful.*

`$which python` returns `Python 2.5.4`

`$python print sys.path` uses `Python 2.5.4 / GCC 4.0.1` and returns:

```
'',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python25.zip'
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5'
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/plat-darwin'
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/plat-mac'
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages'
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/lib-tk'
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload'
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages'
```

`$python2.5 print sys.path` uses `Python 2.5.4 / GCC 4.0.1` and returns the same as above

`$python2.7 print sys.path` uses `Python 2.7.2 / GCC 4.2.1` and returns:

```
'',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip'
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7'
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin'
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac'
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages'
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python'
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk'
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old'
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload'
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC'
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages'
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL'
```

Comment: A library build with/for python 2.7 won't work with python 2.5.  You will need to rebuild PIL making sure that you compile against python 2.5.

Comment: That's what I have done, or tried to. 2.5 can't build PIL, it insists on using a Developer Kit from OSX 10.4 that I don't have with the consequence that I can **only*** build the version of PIL 1.1.7 _for_ Python2.5 via Python2.7. But I haven't any idea how to instruct Python2.5 to use a newer version of GCC or look for a different Development Kit. Rawr.

Comment: The problem is that binaries compiled for 2.7 cannot be read by 2.5, so it's impossible to buildomg for 2.5 using 2.7. I'm not familiar with build PIL, but I imagine that there is some configure step that will let you customize the compiler.