# How to change the linking command in a setuptools building process (msvc)?

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-2015, cython, distutils

I maintain a Cython binding to some OCaml code (through their respective C interface). For past versions, I managed to cheat and distribute a wheel file for Windows through cross-compilation. Now, I finally managed a clean and native way to produce the library for Windows 64 bits.

For the 32 bits cross-compiled version, I had a specific target in my `setup.py` with the proper commands to execute. Back on Windows, I would like to stick to a *setuptoolsic* way of doing, but the thing is I need to replace the regular linking command `link.exe` with a different tool (resp. `flexlink.exe`, shipped with OCaml on Windows)

Don't panic: `flexlink.exe` just builds some assembler shit before compiling and linking with the regular `link.exe`. It is the proper way to link OCaml executables and shared libraries under Windows.

For MacOS and Linux, the traditional `Extension` pattern works like a charm as follows (`mlobject` is produced by OCaml a bit earlier in the file after some timestamp checks, `asmrunlib` is the full path to the equivalent of `python36.dll` for OCaml) :

```
extensions = [
    Extension("foo",
              ["foo.pyx", "interface_c.c"],
              language="c",
              include_dirs=INCLUDE,
              extra_compile_args=compileargs,
              extra_link_args=[mlobject, asmrunlib, ]
              )
]
```

Let's say I limit myself to Python>=3.5, I guess (by comparison with too big projects like NumPy) I would need to start by extending `distutils._msvccompiler.MSVCCompiler` and replace the `self.linker = _find_exe("link.exe", paths)` with something based on `flexlink.exe`.

The problem is that I have no idea how they manage the plumbing work that comes next (connecting this extended compiler and making it look like the regular msvc to the setup process). I suppose it is not thoroughly documented anywhere and that if they were able to do more than that in NumPy, I should be able to reach my goal somehow.

My `setup.py` is still reasonably basic and a solution that keeps the whole building/packaging process in one single file would be great!

Comment: Just in case you don't get answer here, try also the setuptools mailing list: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/

Comment: Found this answer somewhat related, mentions MSVC distutils compiler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212494/get-the-commands-distutils-passes-to-the-compiler/36710903#36710903

Comment: The question is also available on the mailing-list: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-March/030211.html

Answer (score -1):

The code is not tested, but you can try:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext as _build_ext
# To modify regular setuptools extension:
# from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext as _build_ext

class build_ext(_build_ext):
    def build_extension(self, ext):
        self.compiler.linker = "mylinker.exe"
        return super(build_ext, self).build_extension(ext)

setup(
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    ...
)
```